# Conditional formatting from another google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a conditional format for a cell to turn red, if that value is less than the value of another cell on a separate sheet. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule that uses [indirect()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093377) to reference the cell on another sheet.